# Appveyor, GitHub, multiple projects in repo

Tags: github, build, appveyor

[image]

I am trying to get just one folder to build (see above).  I have the following YML file in that folder:

```
version: '0.0.{build}'
image: Visual Studio 2017
configuration: Release
build: off

notifications:
- provider: Email
  to:
  - keith@sol3.net
  subject: CI build 0.0.{build} failed!
  on_build_success: false
  on_build_failure: true
  on_build_status_changed: false


init:
  # Best practice (Windows line endings different to Unix/Linux)
  - cmd: git config --global core.autocrlf true

install:
  appveyor DownloadFile https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.0.0/nuget.exe

before_build:
  # Display .NET Core version
  - cmd: dotnet --version
  # Change to specific project folder
  - cmd: cd Sol3.Infrastructure
  # Display minimal restore text
  - cmd: dotnet restore Sol3.Infrastructure.csproj --verbosity m

build_script:
  - cmd: dotnet build Sol3.Infrastructure.csproj
  - cmd: dotnet pack -c Release /p:PackageVersion=0.0.{build} 

after_build:
  # For once the build has completed

on_finish :
  # any cleanup in here
deploy: off
```

Constantly getting error of too many SLN/PRJ files.  Also noticed that it is NOT using this file as the version is matching the default settings in Appveyor itself.
 Appveyor's appveyor.yml file:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
build:
  verbosity: minimal
```

Can appveyor do this?  Is appveyor the best choice?  Any guidance?

This is my sandbox (tiny right now) and I have several projects and would like each project to have it's own appveyor.yml file.  I do have SLN files in there too and those are artifacts from VS2017 before I switched to VSCode.  Thinking I should delete those now until I need to put a SLN together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default AppVeyor checks for `appveyor.yml` or `.appveyor.yml` in the root of your repo. If you need to specify custom file name or custom path (relative to the repo root), you need to do this in `Custom configuration .yml file name` filed in General project setting. Some more information is [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#configuring-build). What probably happens now is that AppVeyor has not idea about your YML file in the `Sol3.Infrastructure` and goes with default configuration in which it searches for VS solution or project to build.

Side notes:

- nuget is [pre-installed](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#tools)
- I would recommend using paths relative to the build folder, instead
  of doing `CD`
- no need to cleanup at `on_finish`, each build runs on transient VM,
  which is being deleted right after build finished

Comment: Is there a way to list multiple `custom_appveyor.yml` files in the root `appveyor.yml` file?

Comment: You mean root `appveyor.yml` file somehow conditionally redirects to other custim YAML files? This is not possible, but there are a lot of options to conditionally alter build configuration with [build matrix](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#build-matrix) and/or [branches](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/). What is your scenario?

Comment: https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/25629-one-repo-multiple-projects-2-nugets-and-appveyor

Comment: I now have a matrix of environment variables in my settings page and that is trying to build all projects I listed in the matrix.  Nice.  But I am still not successfully building yet...